# Add spaces around cursor position

Tags: vim

Is there a way to add specific characters around cursor position in Vim?
For example, I have code:
    `variable=value`
My cursor is on "equals" sign and I want to add spaces around it. Can I do it without regex?

Comment: [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) seems to allow doing this. Although there are delays (but I don't know if it is supposed to support this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no ready-to-use command that does exactly that but you can do whatever you want with the basic building blocks at your disposal:

```
:nnoremap <key> s <C-r>" <Esc><Left>
```

now press `<key>` on any character.

I'm sure there are many other ways…

I wouldn't create a mapping for that, though, `s<Space>=<Space><Esc>` is good enough in my opinion.

Comment: It's much shorter than mine. Don't think about `<C-r>` stuff.

Comment: Thanks, 's<Space>=<Space><Esc>' is great. I am not used to use 's' so I didn't came up with this solution on my own, but I think that is just what I was looking for. I don't really like to create new mappings but the one you provided is also nice.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>w a<Space><Esc><Left><Left>a<Space><Esc><Right>
```

This is a simulation of sequence action you do:

- `a`: go to insert mode, place cursor after current position.
- `<Space>`: add a space.
- `<Esc>`: back to normal mode.
- `<Left><Left>`: go back 2 characters.
- `a<Space><Esc>`: repeat adding space action.
- `<Right>`: move cursor back to begin character.

Restart `vim` to make changes. Then you can place cursor at `=`, press `\w`. You can change `\w` to whatever key you want.